# monotonically increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $x_n$ is a sequence in reals such that $\lim x_n = +\infty$, then a convergent subsequence may or may not exist.

But what if $\lim x_n = +\infty$ and $x_n$ is monotonically increasing. Is that sufficient condition to say a convergent subsequence does not exist?

EDIT: I meant "$x_n$ is unbounded" instead of "$\lim x_n = +\infty$" everywhere above.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$ then the limit of any subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is also $\infty$ and therefore it doesn't converge.

Comment: Sorry. I meant something else. See the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is sufficient condition to say that a convergent subsequence does not exist. The reason for that is if the sequence is unbounded and monotonically increasing every subsequence is also monotonically increasing and unbounded.

Then for any large number $M$ eventually all the terms are going to be bigger than $M$ so you can not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Sorry. I meant something else. See the edit above.

Comment: @Black  Is your sequence unbounded and monotonically increasing?

Comment: yes. As I edited above, "$\lim x_n = +\infty$" is replaced by "$x_n$ is unbounded" everywhere in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously, if $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \infty$ then there is no convergent subsequence, since by definition, for every $M$ eventually all terms of the sequence will be bigger than $M$.

Now, if $x_n$ is unbounded, then nothing prevents your sequence from having convergent subsequences. Consider $x_n$ defined by
$$ x_{2n} = 1/n,\ x_{2n+1}=n$$
This sequence has one sub-sequence converging to zero, but the sequence itself is unbounded.

---

If the sequence is increasing it has a limit, finite or not. If the sequence is unbounded and increasing the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I did not refer to $\lim x_n = +\infty$ and I already indicated I know that unboundedness does not imply absence of a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Well, if in addition to being unbounded the sequence is increasing, there is only one option: the limit is $+\infty$. Any existence of a converging subsequence would contradict monotonicity and unboundedness...